Zwei Fragen über Passivsätze ohne Subjekt
Ich bin dabei, das Thema „Passivsätze ohne Subjekt" mit der Hilfe von „Grammatik Aktiv B2-C1" zu wiederholen und ich verstehe zwei Antworte auf die Übungen nicht.
1.

Formen Sie die Sätze ins unpersönliche Passiv um:
Man hat den Schulen neue Lehrstellen bewilligt.

Ich habe mit

Den Schulen ist neue Lehrerstellen bewilligt worden

geantwortet, weil ich auf diese im Buch zu findende Hinweisung geachtet habe

Das konjugierte Verb steht immer in der 3. Person Singular

Trotzdem ist es mir komisch erschienen, weil mir schien, dass der Verb im Plural sein sollte.  Und die Lösung im Buch lautet:

Den Schulen sind neue Lehrerstellen bewilligt worden.

Aber ist das tatsächlich ein Passivsatz ohne Subjekt, oder einfach das Zustandspassiv, oder....? Was geht hier eigentlich vor?
2.
Die Übung ist

Formen Sie die Sätze um, sodass es entfallen kann:
Es wurde auf ein angemessenes Angebot vergeblich gewartet

und die Lösung lautet

Auf ein angemessenes Angebot wurde vergeblich erwartet

Gibt es einen Grund, warum "gewartet" zu "erwartet" geändert wird?

Da die beiden Teile dieser Frage nichts miteinander zu tun haben, stelle nächstes Mal besser zwei getrennte Fragen.

Dies sind ja tatsächlich zwei unabhängige Fragen, handeln wir sie nacheinander ab. Generell: Dein Gefühl ist richtig in beiden Fällen und Deine Lehrmaterialien scheinen nicht sehr gut korrekturgelesen worden zu sein:

Der Passivsatz hat ein Subjekt (hier hervorgehoben):


Den Schulen sind neue Lehrerstellen bewilligt worden.

Dem Plural des Subjekts "neue Lehrerstellen" folgend muss das Verb in der Pluralform stehen (also "sind").

Das muss sich um einen Übertragunsfehler handeln. Das Verb sollte sich nicht ändern und es müsste, genau wie Du erwartest, "gewartet" heißen:


Auf ein angemessenes Angebot wurde vergeblich gewartet.


Danke -- also der Akkusativ ("neue Lehrstellen") im Originalsatz wird das Subjekt im Passivsatz?

Das ist hier korrekt, ja. (Nebenbemerkung: achte auf den Unterschied: Lehrstellen = Ausbildungsstellen für Berufs-Schüler; Lehrerstellen = Arbeitsplätze für Lehrer - hier wird vermutlich letzteres gemeint sein)

Der erste Satz ist allerdings Vorgangspassiv, nicht Zustandspassiv, den sind worden ist die Plural Perfekt von werden.
